# sculpting is slow on high dpi display

Tags: sculpting, performance

I was about to learn sculpting in blender, and I noticed it's very slow. Just the sculpting. Navigation and everything else is very performant. I tried scaling the blender window so it's 1/4 of my screen, then there's a significant performance increase. It's performant when I split the blender view-port into a little section as well (two view-ports). What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see many people having issue with viewport performances. try to switch 2.8, 2.81- or 2.79 stable version if that does anything good. For me 2.8 is better to sculpt- but for some its the other way around.

Comment: hi! thanks for the suggestion. i tried using 2.81 and 2.79. unfortunately that didn't fix it. i'm sure it has something to do with my display's pixel density (as evident by the increase in performance as i scale the window down). guess it's back to ZBrush for me 

Comment: Im sure you tried a different video driver. I mostly use Sculptris to do sculpting. Not really happy with how blender deals with high polygons atm ;)